# How do i try to open up the putty console/command prompt

Tags: ubuntu, putty

Please I was using the putty console and my laptop went off. On oning it Again I couldn't bring back the outty/console or Ubuntu console. Please is they any way around it or do I have to install it from the beginning again or can I use command prompt to open it

Answer (score 0):

Typical, new contributor, but instant -1 from someone.

Anyway, if you want to open putty from console just type

```
>> putty
```

> I couldn't bring back the putty/console or **Ubuntu console**.

What do you mean, Ubuntu consoles? The terminal doesn't work?